# compare a part of a cell with the another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a help with excell tables. I need to compare a only part of a cell with another column actually I need to see if the data exists.

The cell part would be the first 4 letters left(s2;4) with b1:b1000

I have tried with:

=IF(AND(LEFT($B$1:$B$1000;4)=LEFT(S2;4));"match";"no match")

but it doesnt seem to search thorough the whole column $B$1:$B$1000 but it compares s2 with b2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to see if the string exists in the search list (presumably B1-1000) - this should work for you.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$1000,"*"&LEFT(S2,4)&"*")>0,"Match","No Match")
```

Comment: You can use countif to do this kind of one to many check - and can wrap your search string in wildcards (*) to look within the cell.

If you only want instances at the start, take out the first "*"&